# Wrapping function pointer

Tags: c

I am trying to wrap a library for porting purpose. The library exposes a function say -

```
fooLib(int , char , function pointer A);
```

signature of the function pointer A is

```
void handler(DataFormat);
```

where `DataFormat` is a struct

I don't want my wrapper to expose this library's callback function. I want to create a different function that should be used by the consumers of my wrapper, say

```
int handlerNew(NewDataFormat);
```

where `NewDataFormat` is my struct

The question now is how can I link these two functions? Whenever the library calls `handler` I want it to call my callback `handlerNew` after filling up the `NewDataFormat` struct from the `DataFormat`.

Comment: Sometimes callback registration will accept a `void *` in addition to the function pointer, and then pass that `void *` to the callback function. This allows custom data to be "attached" to the function pointer. Without that feature, this is very difficult.

Comment: thats true, but this library does not take any void* pointer.

Comment: It's a bit unclear how all the bits fit together. How is `fooLib` used? How/when does the library invoke `handler`? How does the client code use your wrapper - you have only said the wrapper has a `handlerNew` function but imply that this is called by the library and not the client code. So what does the client code invoke - the original library or your wrapper?

Comment: The excellent answer from @Gene below is what you're looking for. There's no point your new handler's prototype returning an int. The wrapped library won't consume it because it's expecting the call back to return nothing. Also bear in mind that if you're wrapping this library so that it can be called from a different language, remember that the handler you supply has to have C calling conventions. Not so much of a problem if that language is C++ (`extern "C" { void realHandler(NewDataFOrmat);}`), might be a bit trickier in other languages.

Comment: I agree there is no point having an int return. I am going to use it only in C.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As long as you don't need thread safety, this is not hard. You just have to provide a private (static) handler with the library's interface that transforms the library data struct into your wrapped version, then calls your callback with that as an argument.  Your interface will look like:

```
// wrapped_foo_lib.h
typedef struct { ... } NewDataFormat;
typedef void (*WRAPPED_CALLBACK)(NewDataFormat);
void wrappedFooLibCall(int x, char c, WRAPPED_CALLBACK cb);
```

Your implementation, which the client never gets to see is:

```
// wrapped_foo_lib.c
// This static var makes this module _not_ thread safe.
static WRAPPED_CALLBACK wrapped_callback;

static void private_handler(DataFormat data) {
  NewDataFormat new_data = ...; // extract new_data from data
  wrapped_callback(new_data);
}

void wrappedFooLibCall(int x, char c, WRAPPED_CALLBACK cb) {
  wrapped_callback = cb;      
  foo_lib(x, c, private_handler);
}
```

The non-thread safety is why *every API callback should include a `void *` that you get to define, which is passed on to the callback*. I.e. your furnished library *should* be defined as

```
fooLib(int, char, void (*)(DataFormat, void *env));
void handler(DataFormat, void *env);
```

Now when you call `fooLib`, you furnish any struct at all as `env`, and it's passed back to you. This way you can dispense with the static variable in the wrapper:

```
// wrapped_foo_lib.c
typedef struct { WRAPPED_CALLBACK wrapped_callback; } ENV;

static void private_handler(DataFormat data, void *void_env) {
  ENV *env = (ENV*)void_env;
  NewDataFormat new_data = ...; // extract new_data from data
  env->wrapped_callback(new_data);
}

void wrappedFooLibCall(int x, char c, WRAPPED_CALLBACK cb) {
  ENV env[1] = {{ cb }};      
  foo_lib(x, c, env);
}
```

This is thread safe because `ENV` is stack allocated. A nice example of this done well is the libpng.

Feel free to update the C90 to more modern syntax.

Comment: In GCC at least you can get round the thread safety issue by changing `static WRAPPED_CALLBACK wrapped_callback;` to `__thread WRAPPED_CALLBACK wrapped_callback;`. The wrapped_callback variable is then a thread-global variable, so can be safely set per thread.

Comment: This will work, the only concern is if my customers want  to register multiple callback, then only the last registered callback will be remembered by the static variable. Is there any around this.

Comment: @Saaras, wrappedFooLibCall could take a list or array of call back function pointers instead of a single pointer. The static variable could be a copy of that list, and the private handler would simply iterate over the list calling each handler in turn.

Comment: @bazza, can you please elaborate on the iteration part. I am struck on this for past 2 days.How would the `private_handler` know which `wrapped_callback` to call ?

Comment: @Saaras, simply create and pass something to store a list of callbacks, e.g. an array of function pointers. The private_handler would be able to call every call back function inside a `for` loop. If you want something more selective, have an array of flags too to mark which call backs should be called, something like `if (flag[i]) callback[i](NewDataFormat);`

Comment: @Saaras I'm not sure what you mean by "register". You didn't say anything about a callback registry. The user is free to call the entry point wrappedFooLibCall(int x, char c, WRAPPED_CALLBACK cb) with as many different callbacks as she wishes. The static variable is only used while the call is in progress to capture the callback pointer so that the private handler can see it.  As bazza said, you can solve the thread safety problem with thread local storage, but this is like using a baseball bat to scratch your head.